# how to access files from system to another system in java programming?

Tags: java, file, writer

i am running a web service in java and it will called by .net application .we have another application regarding this which is a java application(front end), my question is while calling the web service , it will be shown the java application log file. so how to access the file in that application in web service to write the log.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to access a file on another system is to use NFS or SMB. Mount the directory where the file(s) are and access them as if they were local to the system you want to access them with.